# Two texts with the same width on two different lines, but with different font sizes

Tags: formatting, tikz-styles, titlesec, ifthenelse

I want to create a new command for a template cover, and I think a specific type of formatting would look great, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Essentially, what I want to do is have a title with two lines, and the text on each line should have the same length, but not the same font size, for example:
[image]
However, I can't create a command that optimizes this process. Doing it manually is straightforward, but constantly changing dimensions is not the most efficient way to do things. So far, what I've thought of is the following:

**.cls file**

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{igclass}[2023/10/10 Custom template]

\LoadClass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{book}

\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[default,oldstyle,scale=0.95]{opensans}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\RequirePackage[top = 2.5cm,
                bottom = 3.8cm,
                left = 2cm,
                right = 2cm,
                ]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\definecolor{myDColor}{HTML}{101010}
\definecolor{myLColor}{HTML}{7736d9}

\newcommand{\pretitle}[2]{%
\begin{titlepage}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \newlenght{\longest}
    \newcommand{\texta}{#1}
    \newcommand{\textb}{#2}
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{{\widthof{\texta}}>{\widthof{\textb}}}}
    {
      \setlength{\longest}{\widthof{\texta}}
    }
    {
      \setlength{\longest}{\widthof{\textb}}
    }
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % BACKGROUND
    \fill[white] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
    
    \node[%
        myDColor,
        rounded corners,        
        minimum height  = 3cm,         
        minimum width   = 0.625*\paperwidth,
        right,
    ] (title) at ($(current page.west)+(1,2)$){%
        {\fontsize{45}{60} \selectfont \bfseries \MakeUppercase{
            \parbox{\widthof{#1}}{
                #1\\ 
                #2
            }
        }
    }
};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

**.tex file**

```
\documentclass{igclass}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\pretitle{A long text for title}{and a small}

\end{document}
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: `microtype`, possibly. `text along path` from `decorations.text` (but this is not fast).

Comment: Incidentally, loading `opensans` with `default` does nothing since you later load `lmodern`. `\newlenght` surely gives you an error?

Comment: What about the fontsize relation of both lines. Do you want a fixed ratio? Or both just filling the line width?

Comment: If the font size does not matter and only the width is important, you could use `\resizebox{10cm}{!}{text}`.

Comment: @Arne oops I just posted an answer then saw your comment sorry, if you post I'll delete:-)

Comment: @David Carlisle sure, thanks.

Comment: Jimeens, sorry could you move your accept to @Arne's answer so I can delete mine, see the above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}


\bfseries\sffamily
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{A LONG TEXT FOR TITLE}

\medskip

\resizebox{12cm}{!}{AND A SMALL}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine your `\node` command in your `cls` file within the macro `\pretitle` to

```
\node[%
    myDColor,
    rounded corners,
    right,
    text width=\linewidth
] (title) at ($(current page.west)+(1,2)$){%
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#1}}\\[1em]
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\bfseries \MakeUppercase{#2}}
};
```

Then, this will yield the following:
[image: example image for the compiled file]